# what is the package for addressbook_pb2

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, addressbook

while going through the [python tutorial for google protocol](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial) buffers I saw the examples call a library `addressbook_pb2`. I tried to do `pip install addressbook_pb2` with no results. What is the package or steps needed to install the library

Answer (score 0):

In the section "Where to Find the Example Code", there is a link for Source code. Go to the [Github Python Branch](https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/python) and follow the instructions under "Installation" section.